# Unable to inflate layout with material components using service context

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-service

A Service has to inflate a layout to show as a floating widget. I'm able to infalte with non-material UI components. But when I use material components like button, app crashes with following error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.example.WindowService: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #82: Binary XML file line #82: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3740)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:235)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1784)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6981)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #82: Binary XML file line #82: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #82: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at android.view.View.inflate(View.java:26170)
    at com.example.WindowService.onCreate(WindowService.kt:29)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3728)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:235)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1784)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6981)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
    at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:240)
    at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkMaterialTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:215)
    at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkCompatibleTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:143)
    at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainStyledAttributes(ThemeEnforcement.java:78)
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.<init>(MaterialButton.java:200)
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.<init>(MaterialButton.java:191)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at android.view.View.inflate(View.java:26170) 
    at com.example.WindowService.onCreate(WindowService.kt:29) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3728) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:235) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1784) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6981) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
```

Inside Service onCreate. The line throws above error.

```
floatingView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.floating_view, null)
```

floating_layout contains ConstraintLayout with databinding and below material widget.

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/material_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/device_name"/>
```

I tried changing AppTheme to few available material themes for `<application>` tag, but still same issue.

Comment: Does your layout rendering is ok?

Comment: Yes. Same layout works for Activity and Fragment.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
    Have a look this line

Comment: "I tried changing AppTheme to few available material themes for <application> tag, but still same issue."

Comment: Try inflate layout with theme `View.inflate(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.AppTheme), R.layout.floating_view)`

Comment: Maybe your probelem is getting `inflater` , try  `LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(...)`

Comment: @StanislavBondar It worked. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per *@StanislavBondar*'s comment, able to inflate layout with material components in service.

```
floatingView = View.inflate(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.AppTheme), R.layout.floating_view)
```